# How to generate a random Normal distribution that variate slowly?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, normal-distribution

I want to
I want to generate a random Normal distribution that has a slow variation to imitate the slow-fading. I Use Matlab so I did this:

```
pd_lp = makedist('Normal','mu',2,'sigma',1);
R_lp_base = random(pd_lp,5000,1);
figure()
plot(R_lp_base)
```

This code only generates a normal distribution but the variation is rapid. So I have thought of generating a Normal distribution with less samples and Interpolate it like this:

```
pd_lp = makedist('Normal','mu',2,'sigma',1);
R_lp_base = random(pd_lp,50,1);
R_lp=interp1(1:50,R_lp_base,linspace(1,50,5000)','spline');
figure
plot(R_lp)
```

As you can see the "R_lp" is variating slowly but it does not follow a Normal distribution (verified through the K-S test : kstest(R_lp)).

Can anyone please help me to generate a Normal distibution with 5000 samples that variates slowly ?

Comment: I might not understand your intent. The "rapid variation" I assume is between subsequent points? The normal variation is identical and independently distributed, so the difference between any two samples (including adjacent samples) is also IID and normal.  Of course, the interpolation in the second example ensures that the difference between adjacent samples is not normal, and therefore R_lp itself cannot be normal either. You don't need a test for that.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you for you response. If you plot the two codes you will get the idea of "rapid Variation and slow variation". I refer to "rapid variation" to a signal that variates quickly shuch as "R_lp_base" while "R_lp" variates slowly comapared to "R_lp_base". My question is : is there any way to generate a signal Normally distributed and variates slowly at the same time ?

Comment: The problem with that statement seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of stochastic signals. Do you know and understand the concept of IID, Identical and Independently Distributed? Can you calculate the mean and standard deviation of the **difference** between two variables, when they both have the same  normal (gaussian)  distribution with mean 2 and standard deviation 3 ? The short answer is "No, you can't generate such a signal, because it cannot even exist."